# Where can I find an ICQ library for C#?

Tags: c#, .net, protocols, instant-messaging

Is there any (preferably native) C# library which allows me to send some messages via the ICQ protocol? Is there something better than just wrapping libgaim or something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps this can help you out:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/oscarlib/

Download the source and check the OscarLib.

Comment: The link was dead, I changed it to sourceforge

Answer (score 1):

There aren't any libraries I know of, so if you want to do this in C# you're probably going to have to make it yourself. You can find the ICQ protocol specification [here](http://iserverd.khstu.ru/oscar/).

Answer (score 1):

You could try the Across Communications web service.

Sample: http://www.acrosscommunications.com/DevSampleCS.aspx?Object=SOAP:ICQ&Detail=-sample-&Lang=CS

Answer (score 1):

Try using Icq# - http://icq-sharp.sourceforge.net/